# How to put css files to head by means UIModule in the tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

I want to add set of css files to head. For instance,

python file:

modules.py

```py
class SomeModule(tornado.web.UIModule):
    def css_files(self):
        return [self.handler.static_url('css/modules/some-module.css'),]

    def render(self, some_data=None):
        result = ''
        if some_data is not None:
            """to do something with data"""
        return result
```

server.py

```py
app = Application(
    ...
    ui_module=modules
    ...
)
```

template file:

```
...
{% module SomeModule(some_data=put_data_here) %}
```

As the result, I see only data that were returned from render. But css files weren't set between head tags.

Answer (score 1):

What's the result of the template file depends on how you generate the template file. As far as I can see, you didn't include the code for that in your question.

If you want to use `css_files()` or similar, you need to use `self.render_string()` in order to give Tornado a chance to insert the CSS tags in the proper places.

For an example of how to use `tornado.web.UIModule`, see [this Slideshare presentation](http://de.slideshare.net/gavinmroy/an-introduction-to-tornado)